# NUnit. No tests detected in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit

I have a set of unit tests made in NUnit, when I try to discover, run them using Visual Studio 2015, they are not discovered.

It seems this bug is in "Open" status :
https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/117

Is there another workaround I can follow in order to discover my NUnit unit tests and run them in a successful way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an issue with v3.0.8 of the nuget package. Install the adapter via the VSIX from Visual Studio Extensions/Updates, and remove the nuget package.

I imagine it will be fixed in the next nuget release!